# No results retrieved from database view using Java

Tags: java, database, view, jpa-2.0, criteriaquery

I have a view named `V_ENTITY` in my database which is populated with a few entries. Using SQL scrapbook in Eclipse I can easily do queries which return desired results.

However, when I try to retrieve the entries from my DAO class, I get nothing. My count returns 0 as number of entries, while there are 7 of them, which I can fetch with native SQL queries via scrapbook.

I have created a separate entity for that particular view:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_ENTITY")
public class ViewEntity {
    ...
}
```

I use JPA2 CriteriaQuery API for dynamic queries I do. Here is the example for count that is bugging me:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ViewEntity> transactionQuery = cb.createQuery(ViewEntity.class);
    Root<ViewEntity> ViewEntityRoot = transactionQuery.from(ViewEntity.class);

    Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[<someSize>]
    predicates[<someIndex>] = cb.equal(
        root.get("foreignName").as(String.class),
        "%" + foreignName + "%"
    )

    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    countQuery.select(cb.count(ViewEntityRoot));
    countQuery.where(predicates);

    TypedQuery<Long> finalQuery = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery);
    return finalQuery.getSingleResult().intValue();
```

Can anyone help me find a flaw in my code/thinking?

Comment: Use the `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` property to show us the generated sql pls.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CriteriaQuery, nor with ScrapBook. But my first idea is: Did you commit your values to the database? As long as they're not commited, they're only visible for the user who inserted the values.

Comment: @Templar, please post your comment as an answer, I found the solution with your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` property to show us the generated sql pls